# groupby and select columns from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, select, group-by, aggregate

I have a DataFrame at daily level :

```
    day   | type| rev |impressions| yearmonth
2015-10-01| a   | 1999| 1000      |201510
2015-10-02| a   | 300 | 6777      |201510
2015-11-07| b   | 2000| 4999      |201511
```

`Yearmonth` is a column I added to the DataFrame. Task is to group by `yearmonth`, ( and may be `type` and then `sum` up all the columns(or select a value) and select them as the new DataFrame.

On grouping the above DataFrame, we should be getting **one row for one month .**

```
yearmonth| type| rev |impressions
201510   |  a  | 2299| 7777 
201511   |  b  | 2000| 4999
```

Let us say `df` is the DataFrame , I tried doing

`test = df.groupby('yearmonth')`

I checked the methods available for test ( test.)  but I did not see anything where we can select columns and also aggregate them there ( I guess we can use `agg` for `sum`) .

Any inputs?

Comment: What did you plan to do with the `type` column which is non-numeric.  Did you also want to group by that, or should it simply be ignored?

Comment: @Alexander: for now I think I will just need to select it as is

Comment: `df.groupby(['yearmonth'])['rev', 'impressions'].sum()`, or `df.groupby(['yearmonth', 'type'])['rev', 'impressions'].sum()`

Comment: @Alexander:thanks, it works. I understand that type has to be a part of the key , here is a scenario I want to handle, let us say for `201510` - in the second row , type value was 'a' but the result should still remain the same as the result I mentioned

Comment: @Alexander : when I print the dataframe returned by `df.groupby(['yearmonth'])['rev', 'impressions'].sum()`, it is printing yearmonth as index and others as columns, if I want all of them as columns , can I remove the index ? what is the best way to handle..remove the index or use it the way it is

Comment: Use 'reset_index()' if you don't want it

Answer (score -2):

add the as_index parameter

like this:

`test = df.groupby('yearmonth', as_index=False)`

here is a reference:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202093/how-to-select-columns-from-groupby-object-in-pandas)